# Set a timestamp for the entire table in cassandra

Tags: database, algorithm, cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0

I have a use case where in i need to set a timestamp for an entire table in cassandra. What i mean is, as long as the "table" is not updated (any new entries added or any existing entry modified), for "x" period of time, i'd like to have that entire table deleted.
I know that the default_time_to_live property field is unique for a row. and the TTL is for a column.

Any ideas how i could achieve this use case ? (PS: resetting or "touching" every entry in the table whenever a new entry is added is a very expensive task")

Thanks

Comment: create a separate table with columns tablename and last_update_time

Comment: Sure if i do that, i can set a TTL per row in that new table. But then, i will have to have a separate thread to monitor this entry and and then truncate the table. I was wondering if there is a way to configure this in cassandra itself